# PopUp-Window as background task Android Application

Tags: java, android, http, android-networking

i've a question for a feature, i want to implement.
I know some applications, like whatsapp, gmail or others, which run in background and notify the user, if something is received...

i'd like to do the same with my application. i've a http-network-connection and want to notify the user, even if he hasn't the application started. is something like this possible?

Is it possible, that a PopUp-Window, like receiving a sms, appears?
(if not, the notify-way in a titlebar is enough)

i've no idea, what i should google or where i can find help

Thank you a lot!

Edit: I found another very cool framework which deals with notifications. Have a loot at: https://www.parse.com/tutorials/android-push-notifications

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should take a look into Services. You can have the http connection listening in it. For the notification I'd use the NotificationManager class. A notification is much more less intrusive than a pop-up.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

[Google Cloud Messaging](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/gs.html) will definitely help you.

Answer (score 0):

If your server can instantiate this 'action' or 'event', by all means don't try to pull data periodically, coz that brings extra complexity to your app and also battery drain to your users.

But if you really, truly, badly need this behavior, you can instantiate a Service from your app's process. This can be done from many places, like your main activity or some other user action, or even from a broadcast listener. For example, our app has some parallel work to do, so we pass this to a service and that service is initiated by a broadcast listener listening for phone events like a phone call or sms.

On the other hand, just like the main activity of your app, your background service can be killed arbitrarily by the operating system any time. So you shouldn't depend on it running forever. You should have ways to check if that is still working in the background. Check alarm events or any other relevant broadcast listeners.